# Is there already a Google+ API?

Tags: google-api, google-plus

I would like to know if there is already a Google+ API available to the developers. I have not yet found something?

**The API is now here available: https://developers.google.com/+/**

Comment: There is native app in Android Market :) https://market.android.com/details?id=com.google.android.apps.plus. So, there is some API but not public :)

Comment: Updated URL to Google + REST-API is: [Google+](https://developers.google.com/+/web/api/rest/)

Answer (score 95, accepted):

https://services.google.com/fb/forms/plusdevelopers/ This is the link to sign up for Google+ API access.

Answer (score 18):

The official Google+ API can be found at: http://developers.google.com/+/api/

Answer (score 14):

There is an unofficial API, *[PHP.GooglePlusAPI](https://github.com/jmstriegel/php.googleplusapi)*, that you can use this to fetch public data. It's something to play around with while we're waiting for the full official API from Google:

**Update:**

I've just added support for feed posts as well. You can use this library in your server-side code to read a public profile, post, and relationship data, cache it in a MySQL database, and serve the data to a front-end as a [JSON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) or [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) service.

Comment: the official Google PHP client library: http://code.google.com/p/google-api-php-client/

Answer (score 7):

Google just announced the developer's page

https://developers.google.com/+/

Answer (score 5):

Check out the following - both work pretty well:

https://github.com/jmstriegel/php.googleplusapi

http://code.google.com/p/javaplus/

Answer (score 3):

I think that you'll find this [article](http://www.readwriteweb.com/hack/2011/06/google-plus-puts-out-a-call-for-developers.php) a good read.

> Google Plus doesn't have a public API
>   yet, nor has it announced when one
>   will be available. But if you want to
>   find out about future developer
>   opportunities, Google has a mailing
>   list you can sign-up for to receive
>   more information in the future.

Taken from article linked above.

Answer (score 1):

It is just released..
http://www.globinch.com/2011/09/15/google-api-released-supports-access-to-public-data/

Answer (score 1):

The API itself is there - it's restful, and requires a client library for each language in order to be used.

Here is one for Java: [Googl-plus-java-api](http://code.google.com/p/google-plus-java-api/)

Answer (score 0):

For Android developers, visit here: https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/