# Is there an existing Google+ API?

Tags: google-plus

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there already a Google+ API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6518150/is-there-already-a-google-api)

Is there an existing Google+ API ? I would like to know if it is possible to access the "Feed" with API like done with Facebook ...

Comment: I don't think there will be any API out until Google+ is completely LIVE. Right now it's in testing phase and google wants to keep you anticipating ;)

Answer (score 5):

**EDIT:** There is now a Google+ API http://developers.google.com/+/api/

---

Old post:

> No, the API is not yet available.
>
> http://www.readwriteweb.com/hack/2011/06/google-plus-puts-out-a-call-for-developers.php

Comment: http://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/people/get    Its released now

Answer (score 3):

I think that you'll find this [article](http://www.readwriteweb.com/hack/2011/06/google-plus-puts-out-a-call-for-developers.php) a good read.

> Google Plus doesn't have a public API
>   yet, nor has it announced when one
>   will be available. But if you want to
>   find out about future developer
>   opportunities, Google has a mailing
>   list you can sign-up for to receive
>   more information in the future.

Taken from article linked above.