# post on a google plus stream

Tags: c#, api, social-networking, google-plus

its a possible duplicate of this and i have seen this [Is there an existing Google+ API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6545560/is-there-an-existing-google-api?rq=1)

now my question is i have seen the google+ history API and also google+ Api..

i have never worked with API's before and don't know where to start all i know is i have to implement a code to post on google+ page for my brand..I understand i have to have the access token to do this.. but can someone tell me where i should start and what i need to know before understanding this and implementing it..

i know there are a number of websites which allow us to post on a google plus page for example hootsuite.. which allows us to post to all the different networking sites at once and it does the same to goole+ as well.. so i am assuming there is definitely a work around to do this..can someone help me ..from where to start??

Thanks !

PS: let me know if i am not clear or my question is too vague!

Comment: It's ridiculously straightforward. https://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/ That's the API you'd want and there's a "Getting Started" guide with a simple example.

Comment: do u know if this lets me post onto google+ pages?? Thanks for the reply.. I am looking for something very specific to googleplus!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is currently no publicly documented API that lets you automatically post to your Google+ page.

There are some tools (such as HootSuite) that do allow this, however, and since you have never used an API, this may be a good path for you to investigate.

The API that HootSuite is using is slowly opening up to other vendors. See https://plus.google.com/u/0/104946722942277428266/posts/LUi2ZNyRHag for more information about what is coming and how you can sign up to request access to this.

Answer (score 0):

Glancing at the API really quickly, I'm not seeing what call you would make to create a post, I'm only seeing a read API so far...

But if you can find where to send the data, you need to look into how to HTTP POST data to that url.

Your main options built into C# are [`WebClient`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx)`.UploadString()` or a [`HttpWebRequest`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.aspx) with the `Method` property set to `POST`

Then you upload the JSON object specified to create the post.  There are probably frameworks to help with AJAX or JSON that would make it easier, but for just making a single type of post doing it manually wouldn't be too hard.

Comment: yes, i cant see anything thing either but there are sites like hootsuite and http://www.d3.do/labs/circleoftrust/index.php which have a work around to post to streams...

Comment: Here are two questions about this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10880021/post-on-google-stream-using-google-api  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7570327/how-to-post-in-google-plus-wall
Looks like not through the API, that page is probably simulating a browser post...

Comment: yes, let me figure out a way now to work with this. its pretty simple on facebook but twitter and google+ are going to make it pretty hard to code!