# How to develop application for Google Plus

Tags: google-plus

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there already a Google+ API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6518150/is-there-already-a-google-api)

Is it possible to develop application for Google Plus? If so, how? I did not find any information about that.

Does anyone have any information regarding this?

Please share if you have.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: then Stackoverflow search is not good because i've searched here and in google before asking it! but you didn't even give the link to existing question! thanks for input though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Google+ API has now been released. [1](https://developers.google.com/+/api/).

Answer (score 1):

Thankfully, none exist.

Google+ is in beta, so nobody is really using it (except me :P) and Google hasn't said anything about releasing any sort of developer's guide. But I think one *will* exist, sooner or later.