# Android Development - Any Google + SDK Or code example?

Tags: android, google-plus, google-plus-one

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there already a Google+ API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6518150/is-there-already-a-google-api)

Im looking for Android Google+ code example or sdk (posting on stream is the most importent thing i need).
I want some SDK Or example like facebook has (on https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk for example).

I thought of that since many sites now has the '+1' button near the facebooks 'like' button (on articles etc.)  I thought why not to publish on google+ if my program already publishes on facebook's wall?
Although Android and Google+ are from the same company , I could not find something as useful as the facebook SDK I gave above.

Any Ideas?

Comment: There is no public API for Google+ yet.

Comment: And the `+1` feature is technically distinct from Google+ itself (I started seeing it well before the launch of Google+).  (http://google.com/plus vs. http://www.google.com/+1/button/)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The newly launched Google+ API: http://developers.google.com/+/overview has support for Java and Android in its client libraries: http://developers.google.com/+/downloads

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT: This answer is not longer correct since Google released an SDK.**

As of 29/07/2011, Google has not provided an SDK yet.

As @KirkWoll said, the only thing you can do for now is add a 'plus' button like the 'like' button from facebook in your webpages using javascript - [look here](http://www.google.com/+1/button/).

Comment: This is no longer the case. See Ade's reply.