# How to use Google Place Check-Ins in android

Tags: android, http-post, http-status-code-400

I used Google Places API to retrieve places in and around a particular location. By parsing the xml files, I get the required places and its details. I need to check in to a particular place. I couldn't know how to request through  Http POST method. This is the request I have to make.
place _reference -- the reference I got from place request.
api_key -- my api key.

```
POST https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/check-in/xml?sensor=true_or_false&key=api_keyHTTP/1.1
Host: maps.googleapis.com

<CheckInRequest>
  <reference>place_reference</reference>
</CheckInRequest>
```

I used the following code:

```
try {
        String myXML = "<? xml version=1.0><CheckInRequest><reference>place_refrence</reference></CheckInRequest>";
            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/check-in/xml?sensor=true_or_false&key=api_key HTTP/1.1");

            List<NameValuePair> dataToPost = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

            dataToPost.add(new BasicNameValuePair("yourxml", myXML));

            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(dataToPost));

            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost, localContext);
            Log.v("Check in Response", "" + response);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

But I face this exception while running this code.

```
 12-19 18:18:58.153: V/Util response(455): <!DOCTYPE html>
12-19 18:18:58.153: V/Util response(455): <html lang=en>
12-19 18:18:58.153: V/Util response(455):   <meta charset=utf-8>
12-19 18:18:58.153: V/Util response(455):   <title>Error 400 (Bad Request)!!1</title>
12-19 18:18:58.153: V/Util response(455):   <style>
12-19 18:18:58.153: V/Util response(455):     *{margin:0;padding:0}html,code{font:15px/22px arial,sans-serif}html{background:#fff;color:#222;padding:15px}body{background:url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAKsAAADVCAMAAAAfHvCaAAAAGFBMVEVYn%2BH%2F%2F%2F%2Bex%2B3U5vd7s%2Bfq8%2Fs0itq72PMLUPvtAAASvklEQVR4AbXBC0JqCQxEwT5Jd7L%2FHc8FdR4g%2BEGtEr8u%2FBHxu7otdzd%2FQPyqlmRp1Pw%2B8aukDfRa1fw28ZtWy4sa89vEb7LCi0zx28RvqgkvouW3id%2FU8pbtWmv5beJXRWNrRmp%2BnfhlHXZm%2BQPi95Vk%2FoD4fZbMHxC%2FryTzB8Tva435A%2BL3rcb8AfH7VjJ%2FQPy%2BHYk%2FIH5facwfEL8iaZcrnKyn%2BAPi57K2VL2WF1hJ%2FAHxQ2tJrg6HteXVjPkD4ge6V3J1%2BF97zhx%2BnXhWb8nacKXlnYPErxNPyfqw4ZYKVuUZdfhd4hmxunY73NICgfWMOvwm8ZQ1pMvlDZdaCic98kjV4beIp8ScpLvsSvhflzqQmqVLB281v0E8pc2bdNne8EayNTPNSbt02PBj4intcKltb%2FNibY%2BLf9aSO%2FyMeMo6XMva3g0vwrWsxvyMeEoc3knZ2g53ZaXa8DzxlHa4J23Jae5aycXTxFPa4WRdXAtdsivckZXG4TniKWtOSlre6y7LG651Wxq5OzxDPGUVIKNwX6ekCv%2B0ddglVPMM8ZQ10FJ4LGVvOEuXRl7OqnmGeEor4Ck%2BtnI1ZEvjDa%2FcPEM8ZQVY4RO9VqUlN%2F84PEM8JQ50cUgXH2mrKlyq5RniOQ4vVjPLHdu86OKGi2eIr%2BgNV6JwljmYO6zlbJsbWp4hPtVrjYpLLV7UHIp7rOVkixtaniE%2BU5I2Nc2FKJytZhTuiac5rLnh4hniEzUbDjXhn3g5W0nNA1aAKm7YPEN8bMecrZYLWl70hkcyBay5YfMM8aHI4aR7xAUVHyirOdhAmRsqniE%2BtOKsRjIXtDzmmRGHVmDFDRfPEB%2BJzMmO01xScdYnVRs6vPHMFG9W4ZrMM8RHouWw43DNhlDWiSVZY3nDoWYc3qzDNZlniPe6w4uoOFjcKhPXuJNWyG6VqjSuhm7%2BiZorUfEM8U5J8nKyMw0tcZLwPxdRtTlUcUgVdGlml0uZ4pqKZ4hr5VUnpSXdUgVa4hA5vHERV1Tp9XhdJTWHksYd%2Ftdarql4hrjQiaPiYLclNSeebVYz5o0W7Ghsa9blmlFtx01rxP8yy5XIPEP8L1W7bjWHlbzhRTwjzXrCK1f3qqSEyBysLVtayKp40yqurcITxJtUgavVHNob%2FinZTWt5VVvWVKvJSttQCkRjb%2FA4vLK5thOeIN6sm9ai5cTFhYRDy%2FyTGpdU0hxkaZvWUrZluTmLims14QniVbywClqgeouT9IZXNWoupGzNqHa3y5LGVYBnipbCSVxcq1meIN54oRXsbEk26S3NmBcZ807K3gon2ZLcxF5tPMVJprlWE54g3nihtbRHm7WjkbxTHSCWwj1r2U4HSMmdQEmWwonNtah4gnhjA9ZSaohmpnpDjWRptDwS25LcQGsc2Bla5sTFtZV4gnixpWmIVWpgRuVwsiV5q7kv0JJcNVIFapydUrHTQKa5IfMEcRKrurSQ0qhsmVR4kea%2B7pIr9NqSrRltWlaxomUgVVyLxBPEYeUGygtszew2KfOBclVpVN2ctCXNidZaaKWmONhc6rKaJwi6xuGkRmWpAkRa7outF9XN%2F7LlmbJmpiCyvBxk%2FtnSqHmGWGk5i2ZcaWBLau5KKHt3Ce%2FsaLMz46VG4cTFm%2FaMOzxFUYWztjzhkNI43JPyYvPAegPxzFRpOYmWF1WywrPUag5xjRapqqxxubijvYFVaC%2Fv7YSDpzxjzlbhpKXxhqcpWshqtECk0Yys6m5utZdD1LCuCifhfyVOapqsxhyiQMmSm58QNdZheZGV5FqwueXiZBUga28DvRte1NQCpQVSUkFqPbIr%2FIxg7arwJqqEg6e5Vuas1Zytyw1ka5uT9ajKI87WbksaLT8mbkXFyWqaa2rOVuFVStUNpGrDoSTPmDfWdlby8kPiHQtoa0vLpXU4WzX%2FS5W2gWxtOHQ24U3CSUmu8BPinR2XVSFyuNAOZ9Fyae1qDu2qcF8suRKeJt7pcW1zaE9xwcVZq7nWtpeTrQ0PrEeq8CTxnsWrlbThELra5ixqbsXWNoeq6nBft6TlOeK9VnG2lfb4TKOOlpOouKPsWg4pb3Nf1uMGusP3iDtKDaTcgMuWvL1FmZOouCtlbwJs1Yb7SuN2Nd8k7mgvXV4OKWALiGkVJ14eyPqQQG9Vc0dWGnn5LnFPTW1z1gW0OdSyag5aHsvaroVs1YZL2dKMt1nzXeKulas52QLanGy3xq4a87Eu2yHZ2uZNWzPjDbDmu8R9a8m7iQNscbKyy%2BWS%2BUzWtqp7qzpA1jPj8KKK7xIPZG2NVWTTSbpKbs5cfEF6y64qV6ctqcKbdvgm8VhSlnWwJbuaV3LzRb11onFt%2BKcVvkl8one7u3bD%2FzJuXnRt%2BFTXVHOWqubQ4rvEEyI1L1Z2h8%2B0eRHLKiBqvkk8IePmxZq1lk%2B0w0nJUHKIlm8ST8ioeVEFtFwbPhA3h8gcdpZV803iCRkVL7Y42bK2w0NlDqXlpJRV803iGZYrnFRxlqwO3eEuN4dSOGlVme8Sz7C37QZqeZPekl0b3nMBreKsp1bNN4lnWIEtF1Vc6i1bVZtwxQX0NC9UrfBN4hk7zaHLNrey1kgVLljATnO2rmj5JvEMqzlrF%2B%2BFXitcsAArnFkdLd8knrFqPmFzyQq0xUm0tJZvEs8oAR0eix0u1ARSqg70NNHyTeIZUqgZ85gdLlgcMjOSRlBqvkk8wwOSp3moJlyoCYfeKkmBVvgm8YyaUJJ5zOJSTXMWSgus%2BC7xjJpA%2BMiquVATXiUcSuGbxDNqmk%2BUxtW82WmurMI3iWd4wifaHo1rNxx2miul8E3iGTXhc4nH0lQ1O80VK3yTeEYNX5SspbEnXFmFbxLPqGm%2BrsvWFFdK4ZvEM2rCt6RmzCWL7xLP2Anfs2M3Fyy%2BSzyjpvmqDoed5YrFd4ln7DRftHI19BRXSuGbxDN6wtdEqjF4lisS3yWeEYUvWlkDNeZKTfgm8ZFu7mqFr%2FKMYae4lFH4JvGBVLgraghf09uQMZdabr5JfKC2q1zV3IgarOLLPMWllptvEo%2B1e7dkq5ZrLkip%2BKqa4lLk5ZvEY15INay9XIqXVGS%2BqsdcirzclYVa7hAPbQFVnJSaC9HCapavqjGXIjXvbNmSxi7eE4%2BsA21OumwuSQUJX1ZjLsVabqR6t7tUlrThhnjEC%2FFy6AKbCy45zdftmEutKm5UcSgHspY7XBEPVAFVHLoCUXPFkr3hi2wutba44QDr5iyeqQ3%2FiAccqOLQDhAV17pG0jZfUuZS5OJaGYiWF%2B2ypOV%2F4q5UQZtDu4G2xK10aeTlC1bhUslciQpYh7PSQtau8ErcVYZ4gXYDcUXLe1lrvBU%2B0VoutFRcWQWo4qwdTlYSr8Q9caDMwc3BDgl3xZpRb%2FORnuVCJHNlla2oOYmLQ8q7Ll6Ie6pgDaQKSCl8IF3WqAgPrbgU2VxpV1kje2EdoOWGlsOJuKMd1g14OdjNp1YjNY%2B0m0s15kYgJVlaFxBVOETuAOK9eEELrDmUli%2Fo8oy94S4Xl2LzQGuk
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This project will be helpful for you:
http://code.google.com/p/android-protips-location/

Search through this file:
http://code.google.com/p/android-protips-location/source/browse/trunk/src/com/radioactiveyak/location_best_practices/services/PlaceCheckinService.java

Comment: Thanks for your response. I got the response. But need some more clarification. If we check-in in Facebook, the message get displayed in our wall. Friends can view it. In Google Place check-in, how come we show that we have checked into a place.

Comment: If you wanted to accomplish the equivalent of what you describe with Facebook, I assume you mean you want the Google Places Checkin to then also be posted to the user's Google+? If that's what you mean, you will need to use some kind of HTML/JS to achieve it because, as far as I know, Google+ sharing is still not that robust and very little/nill for Android in the API. http://googleblog.blogspot.com/2011/08/doing-more-with-1-button-more-than-4.html is the only new news about sharing to Google+ and it is intended for Websites, with a little work you could achieve what you're after. Make Sense?

Comment: I should also note, what you want will probably come in a Google Places API change and not a Google+ API enhancement of any kind. At least, that's what I assume. Also, you should note, when a user of Android uses Google Maps/Google Places to checkin, they have the option to share with Google+ and choose which circles (All Latitude Friends is the default) So there is an internal way, I just don't think that's public knowledge at the moment...unfortunately.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I also thinking of Google+. But don't know, is there any sdk available, like Facebook.

Comment: As I said, not that robust yet...but usable: **The newly launched Google+ API**: http://developers.google.com/+/overview **has support for Java and Android in its client libraries**: http://developers.google.com/+/downloads **Taken from**: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6736957/android-development-any-google-sdk-or-code-example

Answer (score 2):

I Use same link pass the data Using Json. and i get result in this.
Here is the code that i use.

```
        try
        {
             JsonHttpPost httpPost = new JsonHttpPost();

             String MapServiceUrl = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?location=23.180605780303136,72.63688087463379&radius=500&sensor=false&key=AIzaSyClhALvcyStMa-BTWn9a4M9RzQ9sj5SaP0";

              GoogleParser googleParser = new GoogleParser();

              result = httpPost.googlerequest(MapServiceUrl);
              googleSetGetArray = googleParser.parse(result);

              if(googleSetGetArray != null)
              {
                  if(googleSetGetArray.getStatus().equalsIgnoreCase("Ok"))
                  {
                      for(int i=0;i<googleSetGetArray.getGoogleSetGets().size();i++) 
                      {
                          if(googleSetGetArray.getGoogleSetGets().get(i).getIconurl().length() != 0)
                          {
                              try
                              {
                                  if(isCancelled() == true)
                                    {
                                        System.out.println("---Task cancelled---");
                                        break;
                                    }
                                  URL url = new URL(googleSetGetArray.getGoogleSetGets().get(i).getIconurl());
                                  InputStream is = (InputStream) url.getContent();
                                    //Drawable drawable = Drawable.createFromStream(new FlushedInputStream(is), "src");
                                  Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
                                  bitmaps.add(bitmap);
                              }catch(Exception ex)
                              {
                                  bitmaps.add(null);
                                  ex.printStackTrace();
                              }
                          }
                          else
                          {
                              bitmaps.add(null);
                          }
                          publishProgress(bitmaps);
                      }
                  }   
              }


        }catch(Exception ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
```

If it is useful to you..

Comment: Thanks Mike for your response. I need little clarification. I implemented your code. What is JsonHttpPost? I cant import this package, ask to create a new class. And GoogleParser also.

Comment: that is my class.
In this i use this..
HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
     HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(params,TIMEOUT_MILLISEC);
     HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(params,TIMEOUT_MILLISEC);
     
     HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(params);
     
     System.out.println("Server Link: "+url);
     HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url);
     HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
     HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

Comment: you are using this code for places search. Did you used this for check in and get checked in.

Comment: for this i use i use our own webservice like this 

checkin.php?op=checkin&user_id=58&gmap_id=jvvkvvjsb787yjbjcv&latitude=____&longitude=________&locationname=______!

LIKE THIS YOU USE YOUR OWN..

Comment: Jack Sparrow you only need to store gmap_id in your application and all other things getting done. OK.?

Comment: I will try this and let you know.

Comment: Could you please update the answer regarding your last comment.

Comment: in this how to explane you ... dude...tell me