# iOS and Google+ API

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there already a Google+ API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6518150/is-there-already-a-google-api)

Is there a google+ API for developing iOS apps, whith login, displaing images, post statuses, uploat photos, id be very appreciated for some information, documentation... Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

According to the following article it is coming soon.

http://news.cnet.com/8301-19882_3-20075974-250/developer-api-for-google-its-coming/

Answer (score 0):

Google has said they are working on an API but there is not one available yet. They put out [this form](https://services.google.com/fb/forms/plusdevelopers/) which you can register on to get access when it is available.

https://services.google.com/fb/forms/plusdevelopers/