# Does Google+ have a public API?

Tags: google-api, gdata-api, google-plus

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there already a Google+ API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6518150/is-there-already-a-google-api)

Does Google+ have a public API which I can use in my iOS application?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no Google+ API yet, but you can sign up for access to a developer group when it becomes available:

[Google+ Developer Group Signup](https://services.google.com/fb/forms/plusdevelopers/)

Answer (score 2):

Google hasn't released an official API yet. I haven't seen a formal announcement as to when one will be available, either.

There is a [Google Group](https://services.google.com/fb/forms/plusdevelopers/) that you can sign up for to receive more information on the Developer program once it becomes available.

Answer (score 1):

The API has now been announced at: http://googlecode.blogspot.com/2011/09/getting-started-on-google-api.html and the official homepage is: http://developers.google.com/+/