# How to integrate my app with google+

Tags: android, google-plus

Is there any way to integrate google+ with my app. So that from my app, I can

- Read the posts
- Post something on my wall
- Access different circles

At least post something
Did google provide any Api or SDK for this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there already a Google+ API?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6518150/is-there-already-a-google-api)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The API has now been announced at: http://googlecode.blogspot.com/2011/09/getting-started-on-google-api.html and the official homepage is: http://developers.google.com/+/

Answer (score 4):

As of 29/07/2011, Google has not provided an SDK yet.

The only thing you can do for now is add a 'plus' button like the 'like' button from facebook in your webpages using javascript - [look here](http://www.google.com/intl/en/webmasters/+1/button/index.html).

**EDIT**:
As @ade said, the API has now been announced. so my answer is no loner relevant.

Answer (score 3):

We definitely plan to involve developers and publishers in the Google+ project, but we don’t have specific details to share just yet. Please stay tuned and sign up to receive more information about Google+ developer opportunities. https://services.google.com/fb/forms/plusdevelopers/

Answer (score 1):

You can only read posts using the newly announced Google plus API but you cannot share or access different circles.

More functionality is yet to be added to the Google plus API.

In order to effectively use the new Google plus API you need to authenticate the new user, so that you can serve large number of people or else you will run out of the API calls which are restricted to 1000 per day.