# Using OAuth to +1 and Share on Google+

Tags: oauth, google-plus

Is there any way to +1 a web page or Share on Google+ with OAuth? (I'm creating a mobile web application, and my problem with using default buttons is they may create a popup window, which is not good for mobile web application!)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there already a Google+ API?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6518150/is-there-already-a-google-api)

Answer (score 0):

You can use ACTION_SEND to launch the Google+ share dialog.

```
Intent shareIntent = ShareCompat.IntentBuilder.from(MyActivity.this)
   .setText("Hello World!")
   .setType("text/plain")
   .getIntent()
   .setPackage("com.google.android.apps.plus");

startActivity(shareIntent);
```