# Is there Google+ API for viewing moments and albums?

Tags: android, google-plus

Possible duplicate: [Is there already a Google+ API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6518150/is-there-already-a-google-api)

I know there is a new Google+ API came out recently: http://developers.google.com/+/

However, it is limited to writing moments, sharing, +1 only.
I want be able to view feeds/pictures like Facebook/Twitter.

Is it not available? Or am I not looking at the right place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently the [Google+ History API](https://developers.google.com/+/history/) only supports writing moments. The history API is still in developer preview, which means it is not yet final and subject to changes.

If you follow the [Google+ Developers page](https://plus.google.com/+GooglePlusDevelopers/posts), you'll hear about any updates as soon as they are released. You can also sign up for the [platform preview group](http://www.google.com/+/learnmore/platform-preview/) to test upcoming changes and hear about updates.

Answer (score 0):

What is a 'moment'? G+ stores pictures on Picasa, so you could use the Picasa API to get the pictures. A 'full' API is not available, AFAIK.

Comment: 'moment' meaning feeds.. viewing what others and I have written.

Answer (score 0):

To read from the Google+ API you need to use the REST endpoint.  It is documented here:

https://developers.google.com/+/api/

There is an example of using the REST api from within Android here:

https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/

The example writes a moment using the REST api, but it should be straight forward to use it to read from the public data api instead.

Comment: Thanks Lee, but I specified that: "I know there is a new Google+ API came out recently: http://developers.google.com/+/". My question is whether reading feeds(moments) api exists or not.